# Video width exceeds the viewport size on pressing f11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

I have a video on my website in which it takes the full size of the viewport. But my problem occurs, when I press F11 key for full screen, the width and height of the video exceed the viewport.

Normal Image:

[image]

FullScreen Image:

[image]

Comment: all browsers? or just one?

Comment: Show your code please...

Comment: s on all the browsers and we used a plugin called vide.js for making the video responsive. If we can make a video responsive without this plugin is also appreciated.